# How to design an opamp circuit between Arduino development board and 12 V power supply?

Tags: arduino, operational-amplifier

I am making a detection device based on Arduino and MQ137 gas sensor.  I want to connect an op-amp circuit between 12 V power supply and Arduino so that Arduino has a stable and interference-free 5 V power supply access. My teacher gave me this reference diagram, but I can't specify how to design it. Can anyone give me some advice?

[image]

Comment: Welcome! Your question isn't entirely clear. Can you draw the circuit around the sensor? Do you want to scale the sensor output to 0-5 V for the Arduino?

Comment: Your schematic is just a 1:1 differential amplifier with about a 15:1 voltage divider input, and low pass filters. The labels are confusing, and you need to specify just what the input waveform looks like.

Comment: It sounds to me like you just need a voltage regulator.